# Multiply word search

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have made a simple search engine that can search my database. It works this way: you check the word you want to search for in a checkbox. Result are sent using a form. The issue is that it only searches for the last word checked. This mean do I check 3 words it’s only showing results for the last word checked. Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>"> 
<p>Search for: 
</p> 
Books: <input type="checkbox" name='search' value="Books"> 
Movies: <input type="checkbox" name='search' value="Movies"> 
Outdoor: <input type="checkbox" name='search' value="Outdoor"> 
Indoor: <input type="checkbox" name='search' value="Indoor"> 
</p> 
<p><input type='submit'  value='Search'></p> 
</form>
```

This is my codes that generate the result:

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['search'])) 
{ 
  $connx = mysql_connect('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD') or die("connx"); 
  $db = mysql_select_db('DB_NAME') or die(mysql_error()); 

  # convert to upper case, trim it, and replace spaces with "|": 
  $search = (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) ? stripslashes($_POST['search']) : 
            $_POST['search']; 
  $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search); 
  $search = strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/', '|', trim($_POST['search']))); 

  # create a MySQL REGEXP for the search: 
  $regexp = "REGEXP '[[:<:]]($search)[[:>:]]'"; 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `galleries` WHERE UPPER(`keywords1`) $regexp OR ". 
           "`keywords2` $regexp"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query . " - " . mysql_error()); 

echo "<table>\n"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 

{ 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td><img src=../thumbs/{$row['type']}/{$row['folder']}/{$row['date']}-{$row['num']}/{$row['thumbimage']} border=1></td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>"; 
    echo "<td>{$row['date']}</td>"; 
    echo "<td><a href=../view.php?id={$row['id']} target=blank>View</a></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
  }  
} 
?>
```

Can someone help me telling me how do I get the search engine to search and/or show more than 1 word searched result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem fixed! I replaced the 2 lines:

$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

### $search = strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/', '|', ($_POST['search'])));

### With:

### $search = implode( '|', $_POST['search'] );

And now its working - just if anyone else should need the info :)

Answer (score 0):

You have input fields with same name therefore you are getting the last one you need to make the array for search fields like `name="search[]"` and the loop through your query against the array values

```
Books: <input type="checkbox" name='search[]' value="Books"> 
Movies: <input type="checkbox" name='search[]' value="Movies"> 
Outdoor: <input type="checkbox" name='search[]' value="Outdoor"> 
Indoor: <input type="checkbox" name='search[]' value="Indoor">
```

something like this

```
$regexp ="";
$searharray =$_POST['search'];
$count=count($searharray);
$index=1;
foreach($searharray as $s){

$s = (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) ? stripslashes($s) :$s; 
$s= mysql_real_escape_string($s); 
$s = strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/', '|', trim($s))); 

$regexp .= " UPPER(`keywords1`) REGEXP '[[:<:]](".$s.")[[:>:]]'  OR  `keywords2` REGEXP '[[:<:]](".$s.")[[:>:]]'"; 
if($index<$count){
  $regexp .=" OR ";
 }
 $index++
}

 $query = "SELECT * FROM `galleries` WHERE $regexp";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried to add:   # create a MySQL REGEXP for the search: 
$regexp ="";
foreach($searharray as $s){

$regexp .= " UPPER(`keywords1`) REGEXP '[[:<:]](".$s.")[[:>:]]'  OR  `keywords2` REGEXP '[[:<:]](".$s.")[[:>:]]'"; 

}

 $query = "SELECT * FROM `galleries` WHERE $regexp"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query . " - " . mysql_error());  but I get the info: SELECT * FROM `galleries` WHERE - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. Can you please advice?

Comment: BTW: I also changed the form to: <form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>"> 
<p>Search for: 
</p> 
Books: <input type="checkbox" name='search[]' value="Books"> 
Movies: <input type="checkbox" name='search[]' value="Movies"> 
Outdoor: <input type="checkbox" name='search[]' value="Outdoor"> 
Indoor: <input type="checkbox" name='search[]' value="Indoor"> 
</p> 
<p><input type='submit'  value='Search'></p> 
</form>

Comment: Please see my update in your post. Im getting a: "Syntax error" in the line where I have add all the stars: ***}*** Its like the } is not placed on the right spot. Can you see what causes the issue?

Comment: plz see my update: I GET THE SYNTAX ERROR: ***}*** in your codes. Thx

Comment: hmmm what  I add just keep desipere. In the buttom of your code `}

 $query = "SELECT * FROM `galleries` WHERE $regexp"; ` where the } is I get the syntax error. Do you know why?

Comment: @GernerChristensen this is a piece of code not the whole code its just to give you an idea that how you can tackle with multiple words in your query ,do not make a habbit of copying code try to learn from that

Comment: ohhh okI did not know. Im new to PHP and this is out of my knowlage :/ Can I get some more help please?

Comment: @GernerChristensen yes ask what kind of help you neeed

Comment: I cant code this on my own. Can you help me with the codes so I can replace it and it will Work - this will also give me an idea of how the codes Work - but I cant write it at the moment since im new to this. Hope you will help me.